# Power Shell Cannot Overwrite Constant Error after Running Script 2nd Time?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, memory, constants

I have a PowerShell script with constants defined inside the script:

```
Set-Variable MY_CONST -option Constant -value 123

Write-Host "Hello, World!"
Write-Host $MY_CONST
```

Now, when I run this script once, it is fine.
When I run the script again, you get error messages:

```
Set-Variable : Cannot overwrite variable MY_CONST because it is read-only or constant.
```

I am running inside Visual Studio Code 2017.
If I exit and re-open Visual Studio Code, it works if you run it again (and fails the second time after that ...).

Answer (score 3):

If you use `-Option Constant`, you're telling PowerShell that the resulting variable should not allow *later modification*.

Therefore, running `Set-Variable` again with the same variable name results in an error.

That said, **you would only see that symptom if your script is "dot-sourced", i.e., executed directly in the caller's scope**, which means that repeated invocations see definitions left behind by previous invocations.

**Some environments *implicitly* perform "dot-sourcing" - notably, the PowerShell ISE and - as in your case - Visual Studio Code** with the PowerShell extension.

A simple workaround is to add `-ErrorAction Ignore` to your `Set-Variable` call, given that it's fair to assume that the only possible failure reason is *redefinition* of the constant.

---

- More generally, in environments such as the *PowerShell ISE* and *Visual Studio Code*, be aware that a given script's invocation may leave definitions behind that affect subsequent invocations.
- By contrast, this is *not* a concern when invoking a script repeatedly from a PowerShell *console/terminal window*, because scripts there run in a *child* scope.

---

[mhhollomon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10741691/mhhollomon) asks if using *scope modifiers* such as `$script:...` would work:

No, because in the *global* scope in which scripts execute in Visual Studio Code, scope `$script:...` (`Set-Variable -Scope Script ...`) is the *same* scope, i.e., the global scope too.

If you did want to explicitly ensure that your script doesn't modify the calling scope even when "dot-sourced", you can wrap the entire script's content in `& { ... }` to ensure execution in a child scope.

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped me a lot for issues 

Set-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -Name XXXX -Value "C:\XXXXMAX\" -Option Constant

Now after reloading the profile i am not seeing the errors